# AttributeError: 'Drilling' object has no attribute 'depth'

Tags: python, anaconda

The problem is:

```
%cd e:\IceChrono import sys sys.argv=['IceChrono.py','AICC2012-VLR'] exec(open('IceChrono.py').read()) e:\IceChrono Parameters directory is:  AICC2012-VLR/ Initialization of drilling EDC Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-32-7479f156abda>", line 4, in <module>
    exec(open('IceChrono.py').read())
  File "<string>", line 92, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 64, in init
AttributeError: 'Drilling' object has no attribute 'depth'
```

Part of the code for the problem is:

```
def gaussian(x):
    return np.exp(-x**2/2)

class Drilling:

    def __init__(self, dlabel,):
        self.label=dlabel

    def init(self):

#        print 'Initialization of drilling '+self.label

        self.accu_prior_rep='staircase'

        #execfile(datadir+'/parameters-AllDrillings.py')
        exec(open(datadir+'/parameters-AllDrillings.py').read())
        #execfile(datadir+self.label+'/parameters.py')
        exec(open(datadir+'/parameters-AllDrillings.py').read())

        self.depth_mid=(self.depth[1:]+self.depth[:-1])/2
        self.depth_inter=(self.depth[1:]-self.depth[:-1])

## We set up the raw model

        if self.calc_a:
            readarray=np.loadtxt(datadir+self.label+'/isotopes.txt')
            if (np.size(readarray)==np.shape(readarray)[0]): readarray.resize(1, np.size(readarray))
            self.iso_depth=readarray[:,0]
            if self.calc_a_method=='fullcorr':
                self.iso_d18Oice=readarray[:,1]
                self.d18Oice=interp.stair_aver(self.depth, self.iso_depth, self.iso_d18Oice)
                self.iso_deutice=readarray[:,2]
                self.deutice=interp_stair_aver(self.depth, self.iso_depth, self.iso_deutice)
                self.iso_d18Osw=readarray[:,3]
                self.d18Osw=interp.stair_aver(self.depth, self.iso_depth, self.iso_d18Osw)
                self.excess=self.deutice-8*self.d18Oice   # dans Uemura : d=excess
                self.a=np.empty_like(self.deutice)
                self.d18Oice_corr=self.d18Oice-self.d18Osw*(1+self.d18Oice/1000)/(1+self.d18Osw/1000)   #Uemura (1)
                self.deutice_corr=self.deutice-8*self.d18Osw*(1+self.deutice/1000)/(1+8*self.d18Osw/1000)   #Uemura et al. (CP, 2012) (2) 
                self.excess_corr=self.deutice_corr-8*self.d18Oice_corr
                self.deutice_fullcorr=self.deutice_corr+self.gamma_source/self.beta_source*self.excess_corr
            elif self.calc_a_method=='deut':
                self.iso_deutice=readarray[:,1]
                self.deutice_fullcorr=interp_stair_aver(self.depth, self.iso_depth, self.iso_deutice)
            elif selc.calc_a_method=='d18O':
                self.d18Oice=readarray[:,1]
                self.deutice_fullcorr=8*interp_stair_aver(self.depth, self.iso_depth, self.iso_d18Oice)
            else:
                print ('Accumulation method not recognized')
                quit()
        else:
            readarray=np.loadtxt(datadir+self.label+'/accu-prior.txt')
            if (np.size(readarray)==np.shape(readarray)[0]): readarray.resize(1, np.size(readarray))
            self.a_depth=readarray[:,0]
            self.a_a=readarray[:,1]
            if readarray.shape[1]>=3:
                self.a_sigma=readarray[:,2]
            if self.accu_prior_rep=='staircase':
                self.a_model=interp_stair_aver(self.depth, self.a_depth, self.a_a)
            elif self.accu_prior_rep=='linear':
                self.a_model=interp_lin_aver(self.depth, self.a_depth, self.a_a)
            else:
                print ('Representation of prior accu scenario not recognized')
            self.a=self.a_model
```

The link to the program is:[here](https://github.com/parrenin/IceChrono/releases)

I'm running a program, but encountered an error. I have made the following modifications, but I still get an error.

1. Lines 25, 90, 104, 112, 114, 117, 120, 123, 125, 128, 131, 133, 135, 137, 139, 151, 163 in the IceChrono.py program and in the IceChronoClasses.py program The content after the print on line 91, 105, 180, 199, 204, 205, 526, 527 should be added (), which represents the output string format
2. Line 19 in the `IceChrono.py` program replaces `start_time = time.clock ()` with `time.perf_counter` or `time.process_time`
3. Use lines 35 and 45 in the `IceChrono.py` program and lines 59 and 60 in the `IceChronoClasses.py` program to replace `execfile (filename)` with exec `(open (filename) .read ())`

Comment: You don't seem to set `self.depth` to anything, anywhere, but you do use it a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't initialized (assigned to) the attribute `self.depth` anywhere in your class.